# Why is math.log incorrectly giving series during apply?

Tags: python, math, apply

This function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0,1,0.01), columns = list('a'))

df = df.apply(lambda x: (math.log((x/(1-x)), 2.5)+2*math.e)/(4*math.e))
```

...gives the error:

> cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Fiddling with it and reading as much as I can, math.log seems to be returning a series. I just cannot understand why? For clarity, I am simply trying to apply the logit function to each column in the dataframe, taking whatever the value of each cell and using it as x in the function.

Comment: You've got it backwards: `math.log()` **takes** a float, but you're passing it a Series. Why are you using `math` in the first place when you could be using `np`?

Comment: I think you meant to run the apply on a specific column.  `df['a'].apply(...)`

Comment: [Series.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html). [DataFrame.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Comment: Or maybe you meant to use [`.applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

Comment: I think you are all right, as I thought apply was taking the individual column values as x, but I'm at sea as to how to rewrite it. I moved to np.math.log and to specific columns but it keeps throwing me math domain error or incorrect type.

Comment: @James That's because `x=0` is invalid since it becomes `log(0)`. Maybe you meant to do `np.arange(0.01, 1, 0.01)`. (I was puzzling over that myself :p )

Comment: That was it! It was the dummy data! You are absolutely right, thank you very much!

Comment: @James Oh, I just realized, `np.math is math`. What I meant was if you use `np.log` instead, it can handle arrays (here Series) instead of only scalars. Although, [using an arbitrary base requires another step](/a/25169298/4518341).